# Is it possible to override xml registered beans with annotation registered bean in spring?

Tags: java, spring

more specifically, I have a HandlerExceptionResolver registered in xml. I want to override this catch all resolver with an annotation defined one, but the xml one always runs.

Comment: I'd take it out of the XML....

Comment: Please show us your configuration.